# Нейросеть, генерирующая животное по скелету

Tags: нейронные-сети

есть задание, нужно сделать программу на нейросетях, которая берет животное и воссоздает скелет этого животного и наоборот. Не знаю за что браться, подходит ли для этой задачи CycleGAN?

Comment: В такого рода вопросах следует указывать что у вас за обучающая выборка и сколько картинок. Кроме того, что обозначает фраза «программа, которая берет животное» ? Имеется ввиду получает картинку на вход?

Comment: @MaxU кстати да, а то сейчас и по текстовому описанию генерируют всякое и чего только и нет

Comment: Датасет придется собирать самому, в интернете ничего похожего не нашел, грубо говоря 2 папки с данными: животные и скелеты животных. На вход получает картинку, далее нейросеть должна заменять животное на скелет, либо наоборот.

Comment: Задача интересная, но тут думаю вряд ли вам что подскажут, это вам на ods.ai куда-нибудь надо

Comment: благодарю, спрошу там